# How to prevent item selected in android spinner

Tags: android

I had a requirement in android spinner where I need to display the selected item as first element (which is element in zeroth position ) irrespective of item selected.Suppose I selected element in first position , then also zeroth position element only should be selected.How to make zeroth  element to be selected  irrespective of any item selected in spinner.
In onItemselected() method I have the item selected as zero , but still the clicked element is selected for as fraction of second.

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Comment: Add your code here..

Comment: its not really clear what you are asking for,
do you want to re fill the spinner with the items reordered making the selected item at pos 0? or you want the pos=0 always selected? if so, put this mSpinner.setSelectedPosition(0); at onItemselected()

Comment: I want pos==0 to be always selected , though I clicked on item on any other position like 1 or 2 or 3 etxc

Comment: In onItemSelected I called method mSpinner.setSelection(0). The zeroth element is selected but its blinked once when I click on an item other than item in position 0.

Answer (score 0):

ok, then set it 0 at `onItemSelected()`...

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    mSpinner.setSelection(0);

}
```